# How to Use MVC Controller and WebAPI Controller in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use an MVC Controller and a Web API controller in the same project, but I get 404 errors for the Web API. I started the project as an MVC project in VS 2015, but then added the Web API controller, and with the default code it is giving a 404 error.

What could be the possible solution? I have tried some solutions on Stack Overflow, but they didn't work. One I tried is the accepted answer from this question: [All ASP.NET Web API controllers return 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556035/all-asp-net-web-api-controllers-return-404)

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);//WEB API 1st
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

**WebApiConfig:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig**:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Web API Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using O365_APIs_Start_ASPNET_MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using O365_APIs_Start_ASPNET_MVC.Helpers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace O365_APIs_Start_ASPNET_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class MAILAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private MailOperations _mailOperations = new MailOperations();
        //async Task<BackOfficeResponse<List<Country>>>

        // GET: api/MAILAPI
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET: api/MAILAPI/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST: api/MAILAPI
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/MAILAPI/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/MAILAPI/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also getting an error restoring NuGet packages in the same solution:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: What does the controller look like that you are trying to call?

Comment: Where do you call `WebApiConfig.Register`?

Comment: @MitchelSellers going to add controller code

Comment: @Richard going to add file code where register is called

Comment: @Richard  i tried adding that but when i add this line      ----GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);---- after Registerallareas in application_start project gives 404 runtime error. By Removing mentioned line i can run mvc cotroller but not webapi Controller and adding line give runtime 404 for both controllers

Comment: @MitchelSellers webapi controller code is default i have simple added new webapi cotroller with readwrite actions

Comment: show your web api controller code here

Comment: @Mostafiz WebAPI CODE ADDED

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to register the routing for web api **BEFORE** registering the routing for MVC, so basically your `App_Start()`function should look like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);//WEB API 1st
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);//MVC 2nd
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Comment: sorry its not working . Actually I already Tried it if you see my 5th comment in comments under question. I have mentioned there that i have placed this line of code after RegisterAllAreas() . I have also updated the question  code now

Comment: Are you sure you're calling your api controller correctly?Because it's working perfectly on my side.Try calling this url but obviously replace my port number with yours - http://localhost:37294/api/MAILAPI

Comment: Thanks I was making some silly mistake .it may also due to nuget restore after nuget error resolved it worked like a charm

Comment: Hi All, I've got the API element working in my MVC solution, but as default it tried to run the solution as a API solution.  But I want it to run as a MVC solution as default and then if you go to the API location etc, run the APIs.. Has anyone else had this issue and been able to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: works great, thank you! would you mind explaining why we musts register web api routes before mvc routes?

Answer (score 1):

Just add one line in the `Application_Start()` method in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);   // This line you need to add
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write both configurations in the same file like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In the Global.aspx file, edit your code like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(RouteConfig.Register); // WEB API 1st
   FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
   RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); // MVC 2nd
   BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two routes mapping the same way. Either remove delete(id) or get(id). Alternatively, you can add action in your route mapping.