# Integrating a Web API and a .net MVC Project (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, integration, azure-blob-storage

I do have 2 projects, one written in Web API and other in MVC , it just uploading the data to azure blob storage , both my projects are in in running state but when it comes to integrating both in one particular solution in VS , I am facing issues in it.
Please help, I am an entry level developer in this industry.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: What kind of issues? Please provide detailed question about a specific problem you have.

Comment: like my question is how can we simply implement a MVC project in a Web Api project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can place both the MVC and WebAPI in the same project.  This answer on StackOverflow may help you:

[How to Use mvc Controller and WebAPI Controller in Same Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201152/how-to-use-mvc-controller-and-webapi-controller-in-same-project)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but my core project is written in Web API , and my other one which I intend to implement is in MVC , so I do need help in how can I do that , because I really don't have a  fare understanding about the API thing.

Comment: Please provide the following information: 
1. Is the Web API .NET Framework? What version?
2. Is the MVC project .NET Framework or .NET Core?
3. What do you use for client-side on the Web API project?
4. Is the MVC project supposed to be a phased rewrite of the Web API project?