# .Net 6 Use default cookie auth and secure specific controller with managed identity

Tags: c#, .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

In my current project I am using cookie authentication to secure my controllers.
However, for one particular controller (which will simply be used as API controller) I want the endpoints to be secured using Azure AD.

My use case is that the application serves as a website where users log in and the authentication is stored as a cookie. This already works. Now I want to extend a new controller that will be called via a Logic App.

But I only want the Logic App to be able to call this endpoint. So I created a system managed identity for the Logic App and now I want to secure this new API controller/endpoint.

I have read many articles explaining how to implement multiple schemes. But I don't understand how to implement cookie auth + this particular authentication method.

Perhaps a different method is required, thus I am asking it here. Preferably I don't want to edit the existing working code but rather have a [Authorize(Policy = "ManagedApp")] policy at the top of the new controller.

Any help is appreciated, I am pretty of stuck.

Current ConfigureServices method (irrelevant code removed)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/signin";
            options.LogoutPath = "/signout";
            // Stuff to store the auth cookie
        })
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: You can choose auth scheme in Authorize:         *[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "a,b,c", Policy = "user_is_contained_in_administrator_group")]* , so for different endpoints you have ability to choose how to authenticate (cookies, basic, windows, oauth etc) and how to authorize authenticated user (user is owner of entity, user is admin, manager, player, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information you provided, it seems to me that, in order to use policies such as `[Authorize(Policy = "ManagedApp")]`, besides the `AddAuthentication(...` definition, you will still need to either include:

- `AddAuthorization`
- or `AddPolicySchemes`, depending on your preferences.

I would recommend following this tutorial, which explains both implementations: https://code-maze.com/dotnet-multiple-authentication-schemes/

Please mind that, in order to use exactly `[Authorize(Policy = "ManagedApp")]`, you will need to register a policy named as `"ManagedApp"`.

Concerning the development of *front-end* and *API* controllers alongside each other, I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717539/asp-net-core-5-mvc-razorpages-and-webapi-projects-in-same-solution/65719732#65719732) some time ago, which may be of interest for your scenario.

In order to authorize all your endpoints by default, you can, for example:

- Have different (base) controllers for the *front-end* and *API*, and employ a specified `Authorize` attribute in each of them, then inheriting from those ([Microsoft ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0));
- Or use `RequireAuthorization` on the endpoints definition, as Andrew Lock suggests [here](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/#using-requireauthorization-on-endpoint-definitions).

Hope this helps!