# How can you create MVC and Web API project in the same project in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, api

I am want to create a .NET **Framework** project that has API and MVC parts to it. In Visual Studio there are checkboxes that I can select but in Rider there is nothing, it only allows me to create an MVC project. 
I know I can just reinstall Visual Studio and do it from there but I really want to know if there is a way to do this.
With .Net **Core** I can simply add an API controlller bt I don't know how to *just* add a controller.

If there is a way to add it manually, please tell me! 
Rider screenshot:
[image: Rider Screenshot]
As you can see, there is no place to add API. I can't even create a standalone API project!

#### Status

- Someone suggested that I create a WebAPI separately and add the config later but I can't even create an API.
- I looked up how to add an API and it tells you to add one line of config but the code throws errors. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39201152/how-to-use-mvc-controller-and-webapi-controller-in-same-project)

Comment: Did you try creating a separate Web API project, seeing what configuration that does, then applying that configuration to your existing MVC project? You'll learn a lot about what is necessary to get them both working that way.

Comment: But I can't even create a web API project in Rider. I'm thinking of switching back to VS.

Comment: If you like Rider...then why not just use VS to create the project, then you can use Rider to do actual development?

Comment: Lol, I have no space for both of them. :)

Comment: Storage is cheap these days. If you're that storage constrained...get some more storage!

Comment: Would you prefer Rider or VS? I like having one tool and switching would also be annoying for me. I want some opinions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228315/discussion-between-samarmohan-and-mason).

Comment: I've never used Rider. And Stack Overflow isn't here to recommend one tool vs the other. I'm not suggesting you constantly switch back and forth. I'm suggesting you create a project with the tool that allows you to create the project, then use whatever you like for your daily development.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll stick with VS but add ReSharper.

Comment: By the way, when I move to .NET Core, I think I will switch to Rider.

Answer (score 4):

You can just create it from the type combo:

[image]

Comment: Your answer is for ASP.NET Core and not ASP.NET Framework