# Route is redirecting to the wrong controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I added these routes to `RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NewPositiveRelease",
    url: "dispatch/{poNumber}/{article}",
    defaults: new { controller = "PositiveReleaseItem", action = "Create"});
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Dispatch",
    url: "dispatch",
    defaults: new { Controller = "Dispatch", action = "Index"});
```

In the hopes that I could go to this url

```
locahost:3000/dispatch/4529707272/171112
```

To execute the `Create` action in `PositiveReleaseItemController`. However, when I navigate to that url, I am seeing the error:

> A public action method '4529707272' was not found on controller 'MVCQCPage.Controllers.DispatchController'.

Can someone please help me understand why this doesn't work?

Here is the controller:

```
using SharedLibrary.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MVCQCPage.Controllers
{
    public class PositiveReleaseItemController : Controller
    {
        // GET: PositiveReleaseItem
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create(string poNumber, string article)
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Insert(PositiveReleaseItem item)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried changing the order of the given routes, but with the same outcome. Please let me know if I can add any details which might help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by simply placing my new route mappings at the top of `Routeconfig.cs` (above all the others).

Not sure why this worked, as none of my other route maps refer to the `Dispatch` controller, so its weird that it was complaining about that.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't mark this as correct, let's see what [so] members in the future can work out based on your initial diagnosis.

Comment: If a *more* generic route appears before your own, like the fefault `{controller}/{action}/{id}`  it will be chosen. The route configuration is just a list of routes, it doesn't try to solve overlapping routes and assign priorities.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
"PositiveReleaseItem/{poNumber}/{article}",
```

Instead of:

```
"dispatch/{poNumber}/{article}",
```

Comment: This was actually related to the ordering of routes. I put my 2 new routes at the top of `RouteConfig.cs` and it now works fine.. Not sure why though

Comment: oh yeah that... its tripped me up a few times too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27478227/495455 anyway glad to hear its working!